# I have a list of users, I need to separate them like below

Tags: python, python-3.x

Original list :

['a.com,', 'b.com,', 'c.com,d.com,e.com,d.com,w.com']

3rd element in the list should be separated by , rather than having as single element.

Wanted list: ['a.com,', 'b.com,', 'c.com', 'd.com', 'e.com', 'd.com', 'w.com']

Tried to separate by commas, but no luck.

Comment: `l[:-1] + l[-1].split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slice operator to get the desired results:

```py
data[:-1] + data[-1].split(',')
```

Learn more about using the list slicing operations [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = ['a.com,', 'b.com,', 'c.com,d.com,e.com,d.com,w.com']

output_list =[]
for val in input_list:
    split_val = [v for v in val.split(",") if len(v)>0] #avoid empty entry
    output_list.extend(split_val)
print(output_list)
```

> output

```
['a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com', 'd.com', 'e.com', 'd.com', 'w.com']
```